# adjoint representation of $O_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image: an exercise from Artin Algebra]

I wonder how to get a representation in $O_2$ since $dim(Lie(O_2))$=1? My other attempts all failed.

Comment: See [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=8Aa4uS6ZcJEC&pg=PA132&lpg=PA132&dq=adjoint+representation+of+O(2)&source=bl&ots=XBWd-eRsrL&sig=ACfU3U3Gap-Kf7erk8QwSSiNw8RUZJLSwQ&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjwh-KRxtHpAhWGlqQKHQJaA_sQ6AEwA3oECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q=adjoint%20representation%20of%20O(2)&f=false), homework $3$ (with solution).

Comment: thank you, so its not $O_2\rightarrow O_2$ but $O_2\rightarrow O_1$ ?